# Setup NuGet packages folder for project outside solution folder

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have the following project structure:

- \Root

  - **\SolutionFolder**

    - \App1

      - 📙 packages
      - Program.cs
      - App1.csproj
    - \App1.sln
  - **\App2**

    - 📗 packages
    - Program.cs
    - *packages.config*
    - App2.csproj

*Note: App2 project is referenced by App1.
My problem is that whenever I rebuild the solution, the **\packages** folder containing nuget packages for App2 project, is added to *\App1* instead of **\App2**.
This is a problem because this App2 project is referenced by other solutions as well, not only from App1.
So it is important to have it's own \packages folder and not to have a reference from App2 --> App1, since App2 is shared by other solutions as well.

**Update:**
The App1 has its own nuget packages installed in it's own \packages folder. I want a solution for keeping each project installing nuget packages in its own \packages folder.

Comment: If provided solution with NuGet.config works for you, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can add NuGet.config file to your solution, which will change default path to the packeges folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositorypath" value="..\..\packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Of course you need to put a relative path which is correct in the specific solution.
A solution-specific NuGet.Config file should be located within a .nuget folder in the solution.

Here: https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior you have a detailed description of this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried your solution, but it doesn't work. I added the NuGet.config file in \SoutionFolder. Also tried within .nuget folder. It doesn't seemed to take into consideration this config file.

Comment: It has to be working, I've been using this technique for months. Please read the article attached.

Comment: What's more, please ensure Package Restore is enabled for the solution.

Comment: And remember that after such configuration changes in nuget, you need to close and reopen Visual Studio.

Comment: your key name should be "repositoryPath" not "repositorypath".  That might help.